# Telegram bot get message count (last message id)

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Is there a way to get the latest message count by providing a chat id? (the bot has access to the chat)

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe look under this object `ctx.update.message`
You get a timestamp and message ID, which is serial in nature.

Comment: What I ask for is, is there a method like ```api.getLatestMessageId(chat_id)```, or a workaround to it, so that the bot would not need to get updates constantly and each time update the last message id, but directly ask for it